# Build a simple HTML5/canvas 2D game. Game engine recommended to use?

Tags: html, 2d, game-engine

I want to start learning HTML5 with canvas by building a simple 2d game. I want to build one that looks like this one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4SgiVCPfPk

Do you recommend any framework or game engine I could use to do this?

Comment: PixiJS is a more recent and very promising looking graphics engine.

https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/

Comment: @mic html5bookmarks, lists jQuery as a framework when its a library, and doesn't have AngularJS in its list, not so sure its all that!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would recommend using [EaselJs](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS) for a 2D game using canvas. You will find some great examples on the site, and a pretty decent documented api to get you going.

Answer (score 8):

I'll offer you an alternative in the form of [MelonJS](http://www.melonjs.org/) Which has some excellent documentation and very easy to get up and running.

Comment: this looks good, tiled map editor tool interesting, good find.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend CAAT → http://labs.hyperandroid.com/static/caat/

Here a tech demo (canvas): http://labs.hyperandroid.com/static/caat/sumon/canvas/Sumon.html

It's easy to use and powerful, it has a good documentation and a lot of official tutorials.
If you are interested to publish your game on the mobile devices, it is the first supported engine by the Ludei.com team - http://ludei.com/tech/cocoonjs

Answer (score 1):

You can try [chem](https://github.com/superjoe30/chem/).

It's optimized for rapid development so it's perfect for a little game prototype idea.

Answer (score 1):

For developers familiar with Backbone, you can try [Backbone Game Engine](http://martindrapeau.github.io/backbone-game-engine/).
Built to work on the Web, and in CocoonJS. Super Mario Bros level 1-1 was written as a demonstration.